# Preload module in VSCode Launch debug

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to configure my VSCode launch.json for my node app. My node command for starting the app uses the -r flag to preload a module (dotenv/config). How do I configure that in my launch.json? I can't figure it out.

My run command:
`node -r dotenv/config server.js`

My launch.json:

```
{
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
      {
        "type": "pwa-node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "My Launch",
        "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\myapp\\src\\server.js",
        "env": {
                 "MY_CONFIG_PATH": ".env"
               }
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also struggling with adding the preLoadedModules in my launch.json, but if you are just wanting to load your environment file you can add `"envFile":"${workspaceFolder}/.env"` to your launch.json and your app should run.

Example below:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\dist\\index.js",
            "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json",
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```